# Java: set precision of numbers in applet

Tags: java, applet, precision

I have a problem in setting the precision of a non-output line.
This line of code writes the string on an applet.

```
g.drawString( "The numbers entered are: " + number1 +", "+number2 +", "+ number3, 25, 25 );
```

number1,number2 and number3 are three numbers of input. Now I want to see the output of the three numbers in 3 decimals. How can I write this line without changing the actual value of the numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.format` gives you control over the format of interpolated values, like `sprintf` in C. It uses [these format specifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

```
g.drawString(String.format("The numbers entered are: %.3f, %.3f, %.3f", number1, number2, number3), 25, 25)
```